# i am unable to install onnxruntime with pip3 .please resolve it

Tags: python, onnxruntime

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime

Answer (score 7):

You are probably using python 3.10
Currently (June 2022) onnxruntime support goes only up to python 3.9

> https://github.com/ivadomed/ivadomed/issues/1136#issuecomment-1141537454